# how to set same color to all label added in viewcontroller using interfacebuilder?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have added multiple label on MainStoryboard and give them same color.
but I want to set color code at one place and apply it to all labels.

I know one way connect all labels in viewcontroller and Apply them whatever color.

but I don't want to connect all the label to viewcontroller for just set commen color.

is there any best to do that. without connecting all labels to viewcontroller set color at one place and apply it to all.

Appreciate for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclass `UILabel` and set the color in there, and in the `storyboard` give the class name to the label and you are done. When you want to change the `color`, you can change it in your subclass. You can do the color change in `awakeFromNib` method.